# Open Microsoft office Applications from my website

Tags: php

Good evening, it is possible that from a link you can open the desktop application of outlook or Excel, word or another desktop application with a command from PHP?.

Comment: There is client side and server side, and there are traditional programs and apps. Generally speaking, short of potentially proprietary headers, server side just makes client side and can be ignored. On the client side, imagine if this were possible. Ignore your specific app, pretend it launched Sim City. What for? Why? Is it playing the came for you? Or a calculator, is it empty or does it have an equation? Or, a hard drive format program. Client side can’t open programs, it can only offer files that s client program can offer. Or it can suggest an app alternative.

Comment: Did you try [anchor tags mailto protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). It'll open the email client but that must be configured as default email program to open. AFAIK, browsers will not let you open just any other client app.